# wp-admin slow in multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, customization, performance

Running Wordpress 3.1.2 (newly updated, installed as 3.0 about a year ago) with subdomain multisite & using the Sunrise domain mapping plugin.

The frontend is fast, the backend (wp-admin) is very slow on the network admin site (www.example.com/wp-admin) but runs at "normal speed" on one of the subdomain backends (foo.example.com/wp-admin).

The server is our own, Ubuntu 10.04 with mod_security (which I've heard can slow things down).

Is there anything I can do to speed up the backend or run a trace somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up enabling WP_DEBUG and found an error - something about `fsockopen()` not being able to connect to my host (I didn't write it down and now can't reproduce it) - and found that it was a DNS issue;- my subdomain (foo.example.com) was resolving to the correct IP (10.0.0.1) but the primary domain wasn't.

I'm in the process of cloning & replacing a live server, external IP 10.0.0.1, internal IP 192.168.0.1; the new server has internal IP 192.168.1.1 (different subnet) and the external IP is accessed via a second interface. Adding the correct DNS entry in `/etc/hosts` fixed the problem:

```
10.0.0.1    example.com     www.example.com
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the error message you found and what you had to add to your hosts file?  Are you using the domain mapping plugin with Sunrise?

Comment: @Chris_O I forget the exact error & couldn't reproduce it, but I've filled in as much as I can.